# Android TextView not wrapping text

Tags: android-layout, resize, textview, word-wrap, android

I'm developing a form for an App: I've added some Textview fields having width set to "wrap to content" but anyway I try to modify the width the Textview size is always bigger than content. Even using Android Graphical Layout it prevents me from resizing TextViews and EditText.

Here is the layout xml:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#0099cc"
    tools:context=".ModuloAlfa" >

    <!--
         The primary full-screen view. This can be replaced with whatever view
         is needed to present your content, e.g. VideoView, SurfaceView,
         TextureView, etc.
    -->

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/fullscreen_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:keepScreenOn="true"
        android:text="@string/dummy_content"
        android:textColor="#33b5e5"
        android:textSize="50sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <!--
         This FrameLayout insets its children based on system windows using
         android:fitsSystemWindows.
    -->

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TableLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/editText1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:text="@string/NModulo" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/ModuleNumber"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:ems="18"
                    android:hint="@string/ModuleNumber"
                    android:inputType="numberSigned" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/editText2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:text="@string/Del" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/DocDate"
                    android:layout_width="158dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:ems="18"
                    android:focusable="false"
                    android:hint="@string/DocDate"
                    android:inputType="date" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/editText3"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:text="@string/Impianto" />

                <Spinner
                    android:id="@+id/Impianto"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/SiteManager" />

                <Spinner
                    android:id="@+id/SiteManager"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:entries="@array/SiteManagers" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow5"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/LavoriAttivita" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow7"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/editText4"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:inputType="textMultiLine" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow6"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView3"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/AffidatiAllImpresa" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow8"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/editText5"
                    android:layout_width="138dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:ems="10" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow9"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView4"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/SubappaltoDi"
                    android:visibility="visible" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow10"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/editText6"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:ems="10" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow11"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView5"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/EsitoVitep" />

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/radioButton1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Si" />

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/radioButton2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="No" />
            </TableRow>
        </TableLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are your texts that should write in Textviews have space between words?
Sometimes developers use samples like aaaaaaaaaaaaaa for testing and forgot
to replace them with real sample datas.

Comment: They are all single words, for example even if the content of a TextView is "1)" it covers a half of the screen.